# How to stop PHP while applying a terminal command using system() or passthru()?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a application which will check it can ping outside but it never stop. How can i apply a command to terminal and stop the action? Example in following case:

```
$ php -r "echo system('ping 127.0.0.1');"
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=5 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=6 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=7 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=8 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=9 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=10 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=11 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=12 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
```

Note: ctrl+c was applied to stop but this will be executed via web browser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done with [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open). For instance, this program will only let `ping6` run for around 5 seconds:

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),
);

$process = proc_open('ping6 ::1', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

$emptyarr = array();
$start = microtime(true);
if (is_resource($process)) {
    stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);
    while (microtime(true) - $start < 5) {
        $pipesdup = $pipes;
        if (stream_select($pipesdup, $emptyarr, $emptyarr, 0, 100000))
            echo fread($pipes[1], 100);
    }

    fclose($pipes[1]);
    proc_terminate($process);
}
```

In your case, you might want to check `connection_aborted()`. But notice you have to keep sending (and flushing) data for the user abort to be detected.

Comment: Thanks, i see in Zend framework they did also: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.console.process.unix.overview.html

Comment: What a verbose, backwards approach, when you can just call the subprocess with the correct flags.

Comment: @Tomalak 1) This describes a general approach that will work for any subprocess not just ping; 2) You may want to run ping for an indeterminate amount of time until the user cancels.

Comment: Just started using it works great, if you need you may use it too :) stamped: https://gist.github.com/1008090

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Pass the `-c` argument to `ping` instead.

Comment: Thanks, $ ping -c 2 127.0.0.1 worked. But very strange if it endless time keep running. Can we not get any command we trigger its processID back in return or something? And enforce later after sleep(4); kill(processID); ?

Comment: No. Neither `system()` nor `passthru()` let the PHP script run, so there is no chance of killing the process.

Comment: Not entirely true. It can't be done with `system()` or `passthru()`, but it's perfectly possible with `proc_open()`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct course of action is not to halt the process, but supply command-line arguments to ping so that it terminates on its own. The argument you are looking for is `-c count` to only send a fixed number of requests. See `man ping` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`system()` is synchronous, so you can't. Ensure that the child process terminates.

In this example, [`ping`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)`-c 4 127.0.0.1` to only send four ping packets.